# Add / Delete Office 365 Users or Password Resets using Kaizala?

Tags: passwords, reset, kaizala

I would like to know whether we can automate some of the mundane tasks that we do using Office 365 using Kaizala.

Like, Adding and Deleting a User and resetting a password for an Office 365 users.These are the common task that eat up Admin's time, that we want to automate using Kaizala.

For example: If a new user joins an organisation all we have to do is pass the details in Kaizala, which reads the info and adds the user.

or Lets say, user sent a password reset request in kaizala which will reset and send them a reset link to their chat.

Let me know, if at all this can be achieved using kaizala with some third party integrations.

Answer (score 1):

Generally Kaizala has integrations with Microsoft Flow for enabling such workflows. With regards to your need, Microsoft Flow doesn't have Office 365 Admin center connector in its portfolio. So, currently it wouldn't be possible to achieve this.